# Could not allocate 1073741824 bytes for row buffer column

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to import sqlserver DB into mySQL DB
When I try to import nvarchar(max) I get this error

> :Could not allocate 1073741824 bytes for row buffer column

What Can I do about it?

Comment: MySQL isn't generating this error.  This is coming from MySQL Workbench, and the question should be edited to explain this (assuming I am correct).  This seems to be from Workbench source file `plugins/migration/copytable/copytable.cpp` ... when allocating memory for one column of one row, it seems to be deciding that the right thing to do is malloc 1GiB... seems a little extreme, but perhaps OP can also comment on whether the data is actually anywhere near that size, or if perhaps that's (not coincidentally) the value of `max_allowed_packet`.  Beyond that, I have nothing further.

Comment: Which is kinda why I thought redefining the field as a numbered-length nvarchar would at least provide a work-around, although if it's a problem in MySQL Workbench then that needs to be brought to their attention somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like mySQL doesn't understand nvarchar(max).  Can you redefine the column as, e.g., nvarchar(4000) and see what it does?